# How to set up r8168-kms?

Tags: kernel, dkms

My OS:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.24-1~bpo10+1 (2021-03-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Something is wrong with my r8168-dkms; every time I install some other package, this appears at the end of the output:

```
Setting up r8168-dkms (8.046.00-1) ...
Removing old r8168-8.046.00 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.046.00
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new r8168-8.046.00 DKMS files...
Building for 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64
Building initial module for 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.046.00/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package r8168-dkms (--configure):
 installed r8168-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r8168-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the newer [r8168-dkms (8.048.03-1~bpo10+1)](https://packages.debian.org/de/buster-backports/r8168-dkms) package
from backports which compiles fine on my system (same kernel version).

If not already done, add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

to enable the backports repository.

Then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t buster-backports install r8168-dkms
```

to install the package.

Related: [bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=960091](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=960091)